Why were functions introduced when stored procedures were already available in SQL Server?
What factors led to the introduction of functions alongside stored procedures in SQL, and how do functions specifically enhance the flexibility and efficiency of database operations compared to stored procedures?
I didn't get the exact explaination.

Try running a stored proc for every row in a result set to add an additional column or rows vs using a function

@MartinSmith actually that's easy, you put the query to get those result in the sproc and then query on the results or join on them. Sprocs can have multiple queries composed to a single result, Like everything inb SQL I find it easier to look at the problem backwards.

This question is similar to: Function vs. Stored Procedure in SQL Server. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

A function can take parameters and return either a scalar value or a single resultset of zero or more rows and one or more columns.
This is composable. You can integrate it into your SQL statements in order to add new calculated columns or apply it for table valued functions.
Stored procedures are less restricted in the syntax allowed but are not composable.
e.g. You can use the built in function OBJECT_DEFINITION as below
SELECT *, 
       OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id)
FROM sys.procedures

But there is no way of calling the sp_helptext stored procedure inline in a similar manner
SELECT *, 
       EXEC sp_helptext name /*Not valid syntax*/
FROM sys.procedures


You forgot to mention that Functions cannot modify database state.

@Alex - No I didn't. The question here is "why were they introduced given that stored procs already exist"  - not "what are all the differences between them" - and the USP of functions IMO despite syntactically only being able to do a subset of what stored procs can do is composability
